# Javascript validation for select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I want to show additional input field(#addvatnumber) when i select country from the countries dropdown list. I tried following code but validation is not working.

```
$('#id_country').bind('change', function (e) {
    if( $('#id_country').val() == 10) {
        $('#germanyselected').show();
        if($('#addvatnumber').val() == '') {
            console.log('Additional VAT Nr. is required field!');
            return false;
        }
    }
    else{
        $('#germanyselected').hide();
    }
});
```

Here is the condition i'm checking for showing the input field, It's not working

```
if($('#addvatnumber').val() == '') {
    alert('Additional VAT Nr. is required field!');
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Can you show your html? Any errors showing in your console window?

Comment: Well, what returns `$('#addvatnumber').length`?

Comment: are you getting any alert?

Comment: i don't get alert, can this be a problem because this country is preselected?

Answer (score 0):

i did a project  Drop down-value filtering using JavaScript  when i select a state then o the other drop-down list show co-related according to selecting state .it's available in my git hub account [git Hub](https://github.com/ferrakkem/Web)

i hope it's may help you